# Enable (positive connotation) - Enabler (negative connotation). Why?

Tags: verbs, nouns, synonyms

I am writing a speech about people having people in their lives who are catalysts for them to propel them to something positive in their lives.
These people enable others to be something better than they had been before.

Unfortunately, I cannot use the word "enabler" to describe those persons with one word, because the word "enabler" is defined as someone who enables drug abuse in someone else.

Does anyone know of a better word for *enabler*?

And, what gave the word "enabler" such a negative connotation in first place, especially since the verb generally is positive?

Comment: Too Localised. I doubt many native speakers share OP's perception that *enabler* has specifically negative connotations.

Comment: IMO, _catalysts_ is already a great choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was unacquainted with it as well. However, that cesspool of slang that is Urban Dictionary has a [relatively well received entry](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=enabler).

Comment: @coleopterist: Citing Urban Dictionary implies it's a "slang" usage, but I suspect it's actually more used in "legal" contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right. [WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enabling) offers both positive and negative connotations for the term.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: this might be yet another British vs. American thing. On this side of Ye Great Watery Deep, *enabler* pretty much exclusively has the negative connotation the OP describes.

Comment: @Marthaª: oic. It could still be fundamentally a "legal" usage though. And the vast majority of instances of ["he is an enabler"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he+is+an+enabler%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books have *positive* connotations, and are nothing to do with drug abuse.

Answer (score 5):

**Mentor** or **Motivator** would work as alternative terms. (I like catalyst too)

*Enabler* picked up its negative connotation from psychologists. In relation to behavioral psychology it refers to someone who assists a person with self-destructive behavior - not just drug use, but addictions or negative behavior patterns of any kind. (Making excuses, assisting in covering it up, obtaining materials, etc). It's not technically a specifically negative term but at least in the US it's almost never used outside of the context of enabling addictions or other negative life patterns.